# c threads don't print correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, csv, concurrency, pthreads

I'm trynig to implement a simple program in C with some threads. In details, i want that each thread read only a part of a CSV file (that contain only four float numbers per row) and put the read values into a matrix. So each thread has its matrix where they put the values read from the rows assigned to it. I'm able to do it, but when I try to print each matrix from each thread the output is strange because some threads overlap the print. I think that is a concurrency problem, but i don't know if the concurrency is on the printing console or in the access to the file CSV, so actually at this point, I don't know if the values from the rows of CSV are exactly load into the matrix. I let the code down here, and even the output. Can someone help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREADS 15
#define NTRAIN 135
#define NFEATURES 4
#define X_TRAIN_PATH "C:/Users/tecnico/Desktop/UniME/Materie/HPC/MPI/Programs/Multithreading/X_train.csv"

void checkFile(FILE *f) {
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error while reading file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

float *getFloatMat(int m, int n) {
    float *mat = NULL;
    mat = (float *)calloc(m * n, sizeof(float));

    return mat;
}

float *initFeatures(char path[], int start_row, int end_row) {
    int index = 0;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    float *mat = NULL;

    mat = getFloatMat(end_row - start_row + 1, NFEATURES);

    f = fopen(path, "r");
    checkFile(f);

    // Skippa le righe prima di start_row
    for (int i = 0; i < start_row; i++)
        while (fgetc(f) != '\n')
            ;

    // Leggi i dati dalla riga start_row alla riga end_row
    for (int i = start_row; i <= end_row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NFEATURES; j++) {
            fscanf(f, "%f%*c", &mat[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return mat;
}

struct ThreadData {
    int thread_id;
    int start_row;
    int end_row;
    float *x_train;
};

void *threadFunction(void *arg) {
    struct ThreadData *data = (struct ThreadData *)arg;

    // Inizializza la matrice per il thread corrente
    data->x_train = initFeatures(X_TRAIN_PATH, data->start_row, data->end_row);

    // Stampa la matrice per il thread corrente
    printf("Thread %d:\n", data->thread_id);
    for (int i = 0; i <= data->end_row - data->start_row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NFEATURES; j++) {
            printf("%.2f ", data->x_train[i * NFEATURES + j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    // Libera la memoria allocata per la matrice
    free(data->x_train);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    struct ThreadData thread_data[NTHREADS];

    int rows_per_thread = NTRAIN / NTHREADS;
    
    // Creazione e avvio dei thread
    for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        thread_data[i].thread_id = i;
        thread_data[i].start_row = i * rows_per_thread + 1;
        thread_data[i].end_row = (i + 1) * rows_per_thread;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void *)&thread_data[i]);
    }

    // Attesa della terminazione dei thread
    for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

Thread 8:
6.00 2.70 5.10 1.60

6.10 3.00 4.90 1.80

5.90 Thread 13:
5.40 3.40 1.50 0.40

5.50 3.50 1.30 0.20

6.70 3.00 5.20 2.30

5.50 2.40 3.80 1.10

4.80 3.40 1.90 0.20

4.60 Thread 9:
6.00 3.60 1.00 0.20

5.20 3.50 1.50 0.20

4.90 3.00 1.40 0.20

5.40 3.00 4.50 1.50

3.00 4.80 1.80

6.30 2.70 4.90 1.80

6.40 2.90 4.30 1.30

5.10 3.50 1.40 0.30

6.60 2.90 4.60 1.30

6.80 2.80 4.80 1.40

5.40 3.90 1.70 0.40

5.20 3.40 1.40 0.20

4.80 3.00 1.40 0.30

Thread 5:
4.80 3.00 1.40 0.10

5.80 2.80 5.10 2.40

5.80 2.70 4.10 1.00

4.90 2.40 3.30 1.00

6.20 2.80 4.80 1.80

5.00 3.40 1.50 0.20

6.80 3.00 5.50 2.10

5.60 2.50 3.90 1.10

5.60 2.80 4.90 2.00

Thread 0:
4.80 Thread 1:
3.40 1.60 0.20

5.80 2.70 3.90 1.20

6.70 3.30 5.70 2.50

6.10 3.00 4.60 1.40

6.40 3.20 5.30 2.30

7.30 2.90 6.30 1.80

5.70 2.80 4.10 1.30

5.50 4.20 1.40 0.20

6.70 3.10 5.60 2.40

Thread 4:
5.80 2.60 4.00 1.20

5.60 3.00 4.10 1.30

5.50 2.50 4.00 1.30

5.80 2.70 5.10 1.90

5.00 3.30 1.40 0.20

5.10 2.50 3.00 1.10

4.90 3.10 1.50 0.10

5.10 3.80 1.90 0.40

5.60 2.70 4.20 1.30

Thread 11:
6.40 2.70 5.30 1.90

5.70 3.80 1.70 0.30

6.90 3.10 5.40 2.10

7.70 2.60 6.90 2.30

6.10 2.80 4.70 1.20

6.30 3.40 5.60 2.40

7.70 3.00 6.10 2.30

6.80 3.20 5.90 2.30

4.60 3.40 1.40 0.30

3.00 5.10 1.80

5.50 2.30 4.00 1.30

5.70 2.50 5.00 2.00

6.50 3.00 5.50 1.80

5.90 3.20 4.80 1.80

6.10 2.60 5.60 1.40

6.90 3.10 5.10 2.30

Thread 2:
6.00 3.40 4.50 1.60

5.60 3.00 4.50 1.50

5.40 3.90 1.30 0.40

6.90 3.10 4.90 1.50

4.90 2.50 4.50 1.70

6.40 2.80 5.60 2.10

6.00 2.90 4.50 1.50

5.00 2.30 3.30 1.00

7.20 3.60 6.10 2.50

6.70 3.00 5.00 1.70

5.40 3.40 1.70 0.20

6.10 2.90 4.70 1.40

5.00 3.00 1.60 0.20

5.70 3.00 4.20 1.20

5.00 3.50 1.60 0.60

5.20 2.70 3.90 1.40

6.90 3.20 5.70 2.30

7.40 2.80 6.10 1.90

Thread 6:
5.10 3.40 1.50 0.20

5.20 4.10 1.50 0.10

6.30 2.90 5.60 1.80

6.70 3.30 5.70 2.10

5.70 2.80 4.50 1.30

7.10 3.00 5.90 2.10

6.40 3.10 5.50 1.80

7.20 3.20 6.00 1.80

6.00 2.20 4.00 1.00

Thread 3:
5.10 3.80 1.60 0.20

4.50 2.30 1.30 0.30

4.90 3.10 1.50 0.10

6.30 3.30 4.70 1.60

4.40 3.20 1.30 0.20

6.30 3.30 6.00 2.50

7.20 3.00 5.80 1.60

4.80 3.10 1.60 0.20

6.30 2.50 5.00 1.90

Thread 14:
5.00 3.40 1.60 0.40

6.50 3.00 5.20 2.00

5.00 3.50 1.30 0.30

4.70 3.20 1.60 0.20

5.70 2.90 4.20 1.30

5.50 2.40 3.70 1.00

6.40 2.80 5.60 2.20

6.30 2.80 5.10 1.50

0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Thread 7:
6.20 2.90 4.30 1.30

6.50 3.00 5.80 2.20

7.70 2.80 6.70 2.00

4.30 3.00 1.10 0.10

5.80 2.70 5.10 1.90

6.30 2.50 4.90 1.50

5.10 3.80 1.50 0.30

4.40 2.90 1.40 0.20

6.70 2.50 5.80 1.80

Thread 10:
5.80 4.00 1.20 0.20

4.60 3.20 1.40 0.20

7.00 3.20 4.70 1.40

6.20 3.40 5.40 2.30

6.60 3.00 4.40 1.40

5.90 3.00 4.20 1.50

6.70 3.10 4.70 1.50

5.00 3.20 1.20 0.20

5.70 2.60 3.50 1.00

Thread 12:
6.70 3.10 4.40 1.40

5.40 3.70 1.50 0.20

6.30 2.30 4.40 1.30

6.50 2.80 4.60 1.50

5.00 2.00 3.50 1.00

6.50 3.20 5.10 2.00

7.60 3.00 6.60 2.10

6.40 3.20 4.50 1.50

4.60 3.10 1.50 0.20

And this is the CSV file

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the threads? What kind of processing should they do? Is there a requirement that the threads should do print outs? Or can any possible printing be saved for after all the threads are finished with their work and processing?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the main purpose of each thread is to correctly load the values of the lines of the csv file that belong to the thread's domain, inside its own matrix and subsequently print it

Comment: What is your actual assignment? Even with todays SSD's filesystem access is mostly serial, the disk can only handle one request at a time. So doing in threads really make no sense. Especially if the thread should print as well, as that requires some kind of synchronization between the threads which makes them even less usable.

Comment: @Giorgio Aveni, Note `while (fgetc(f) != '\n');` is a tad risky as it is an infinite loop should `fgetc()` return `EOF`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would just like my thread matrices to be initialized with the correct values from the csv file, I print them just to make sure of this, but in my overall program I don't need to print them, since I want to implement the KNN machine learning algorithm on each matrix of each thread, and to do this correctly, I first wanted to make sure that the matrices were properly initialized

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i'understand. you advise me to change fgetc or change "\n" ?

Comment: @GiorgioAveni Quite the loop on 2 conditions: `int ch; while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);`.

Comment: Then I suggest that you first read the whole file, divide up the data, and *then* create the threads to process the divided data. If you need to print any results, then do it afterwards, once all threads has finished.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you mean to split the whoole file in smaller files?

Comment: No, read the whole file into one big array. Then partition the array, so each thread get a small part of the original big array.

Comment: And when I say "partition" I mean you pass pointers to elements in the single big array, not create multiple arrays. So if you have 400 elements and four threads, then thread 1 gets passed a pointer to the first element (index 0), thread 2 gets a pointer to the 101:st element (index 100), and so on.

Comment: Alternatively to @Someprogrammerdude – but that *only* works if all data chunks to read have the same size which is known in advance (!) – read the data into a 2D array right from the start...

Comment: About `EOF` – you can receive this in two cases, either because of having reached the end of file or due to an error. If it is important to distinguish then check `feof(f)`, if non-zero you've read the entire file, otherwise some error occurred.

Comment: Combining both SPD and Chux: You are reading a CSV file – so the newline character is separating two data sets – you can use this for reading the data and separating the data sets in one single iteration: `int ch; while((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) { if(ch == '\n') { /* current dataset completed, start over with new one */ } else { /* evaluate the data as before */ } }`.

Comment: One note about threads (in general): Be aware that each thread comes with quite some overhead, among others memory allocation for thread data and stack, initialisation and setting up thread scheduling. You will only benefit from all this overhead if the parallel tasks run long enough to compensate this overhead. Additionally: More threads than cores don't bring any benefit either, you just provoke more context switches as each thread needs time to run (an exception might be linux where multiple threads can assure more CPU time in total for the parent process...).

Comment: So in the end you might even discover a performance *decrease* on introducing threads (if the problem is small enough). Possibly the case in given problem? Depends on matrix sizes ;)

Comment: Extending on my previous loop: `int ch; while(...) { ... } if(feof(f) == 0) { /* failed to read the entire file -> error handling */ } else { /* continue normally */ }` – I'd add that so that you don't even try to start operating on partial data.

Comment: How large are your matrices anyway? Unless being really *huge* you should have enough memory to be able to operate on `double` instead of `float`. The former offers much better precision and should, unless you have explicit counter arguments, always be preferred (on modern days' standard hardware at least). Be aware that even such simple numbers like 0.1, 0.2 are periodic in binary, double comes with far smaller rounding errors.

Comment: @Aconcagua well, my matrices is not so huge, i must split the csv file (135 rows and 4 columns) into small matrices for thread. But my real problem is not the print of the matrices of each thread, but the situation where each thread's matrix is initialized with the correct values. Just becaus this is only a little part of my whoole program. I am developing a program with mpi where the processes are split into several groups, and each process has multiple thread, and each thread must initialize its matrix with the correct values from the csv file, and later implement on each thread the knn

Comment: Problem might be too small then to really profit from multi-threading, depends, one would need to benchmark. More important to me appears that you have a *working* solution at very first place. So I'd implement *single-threaded* first (if you haven't already anyway) and get that fully running with correct output. Then I'd *analyse* which parts of the project *can* be parallelised meaningfully (!) at all (and IO typically cannot...) and only implement multi-threading on these. Bonus (provided you keep the ST version): You can measure execution times and determine the better performing version…

Comment: @Aconcagua I also think that this hybrid implementation between MPI and multithreading makes no sense, but unfortunately my university professor asked me for this implementation. In fact, I'm having a lot of problems doing it.

Comment: @GiorgioAveni Still implement the single threaded version first. In given case certainly the simpler solution, once done you have a working reference implementation you can base the multithreaded version on.

Answer (score 0):

You have some print problem because as you said some threads overlap the print, all your thread is printing on the same time so your input is totally normal.

If you want to avoid this you can use a mutex, you lock it before print and unlock it after the "\n\n" print or you can print all the line in oneshot using snprintf

Exemple of use :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 123;
    char character = 'A';
    char *string = "Hello";

    char buffer[100]; // Make sure the buffer can contain all the character

    sprintf(buffer, "Number: %d, Character: %c, String: %s", number, character, string);

    printf("Formatted String: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so if it's just a printing issue, each thread's matrix should contain the correct values, right? I only care that the matrix of each thread is correctly initialized, so that I can implement the knn on all matrices

Comment: Where does your example code include the mentioned mutex???

Comment: In given case this approach just makes all threads wait for one another at their very end. As purely time driven, there's no control about the order in which the threads print out their output matrices (and you need to make sure the *entire* matrix is printed at once, otherwise matrix *lines* still intermix). In given case I'd prefer all threads stopping after matrix calculation (with all data being stored in an array of matrices) and let the root/main thread output the matrices sequentially.